# Regex, match one character that is not in a pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, csv

im parsing a csv file with javascript, that file styles the cells with commas in the numbered values.
when parsing it to javascript i get the entire row as one string where the cells are divided by commas, as such:

```
2, some text,9740127,"₪ 38,850.00","₪ 5,550.00","₪ 28,305","₪ 4,995",22/05/2020
```

in order to parse the files and create an object from every row i need to match the commas that are Not part of a number, so the end result is:

```
2
some text
9740127
₪ 38,850.00
₪ 5,550.00
₪ 28,305
₪ 4,995
22/05/2020
```

i tried matching the commas inside the numbers in hopes to negate it afterwards with that regex:`(".\s\d+,\d+[.]?[\d]+")`
but i cant seem to target the other commas instead afterwards.

i feel like im close but i cant seem to figure it out, would appreciate the help!
Thanks

Comment: You could match all the formats `(?:\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}|₪ \d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?| ?\w+(?: \w+)*)`  https://regex101.com/r/1XW68L/1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293147/javascript-code-to-parse-csv-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the double quotes are in the right format, one option might be to split on a comma while asserting what is on the right is not `"` followed by either a comma or the end of the string.

```
, *(?!(?:[^"]|\\")*"(?:,|$))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1XW68L/1)

```js
let str = '2, some text,9740127,"₪ 38,850.00","₪ 5,550.00","₪ 28,305","₪ 4,995",22/05/2020'

console.log(str.split(/, *(?!(?:[^"]|\\")*"(?:,|$))/g));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript's `.split()` method for your use-case.

```js
var mystring = '2, some text,9740127,"₪ 38,850.00","₪ 5,550.00","₪ 28,305","₪ 4,995",22/05/2020';
var splitStringArray = mystring.split(",");
    
for(var i = 0; i < splitStringArray.length; i++) {
  console.log(splitStringArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: it is not working because it will split the number with commas too

Comment: thats the naive approach and i initially tried it, but it splits numbers with commas as well which effects the validity of the data.